# How to get the node handler of a functional component in react/react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

For example, in react-native, if when getting the node handler of a class component, one can do `ReactNative.findNodeHandler(this)`. Functional components don't have instances and they don't hold their own refs but, one could make it referencable using `forwardRefs` and `useImperativeHandle`. So, I'm looking for something similar to `this` for functional components. I've tried using its reference obtained from `forwardRefs` but it's not working - It throws the following error: `Error: Argument appears to not be a ReactComponent. Keys: current`

below is how I'm trying to use it:

> 

```
 export const NativeComponent = forwardRef(
  (
    { onChange }: PropsType,
    ref: ForwardedRef<BaseRef>
  ) => {
    const makeNativeCommandRequest = (name: string, params: Array<any>) => {
      UIManager.dispatchViewManagerCommand(
        findNodeHandle(ref as unknown as number),
        UIManager.getViewManagerConfig("NativeComponent").Commands[name],
        params
      );
    };
    useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
      command1() {
        makeNativeCommandRequest("command2", []);
      },
      command2() {
        makeNativeCommandRequest("command1", []);
      },
    }))});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
const reactTag = useRef<number | null>(null)

<Component ref={(ref) => {
      reactTag.current = findNodeHandle(ref)
    }}
  />
```

Then, reactTag.current is what you want

Answer (score -1):

Consider using Class components instead. Functional components does have instances

Comment: Did you mean `FC don't have instances`?

Comment: Yes, in the past. Today it has changed, using refs solves the problem as answered by @kai